# how to use jquery.mobile.iscrollview in form element focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, iscroll

Am working in phonegap mobile applications using jquery mobile ui with jquery mobile iscrollview for scroll view and pull(scroll) to get request. Now am facing issue in form element page. I have page with more than 15 input box when click the submit button I need to validate form If any input fail need to focus that input box. I try with normal

document.getElmentById('inputfieldId').focus(); - focusing but not visible i.e not scrolling

$('#inputfieldId').focus(); - focusing but not visible i.e not scrolling

$("#pageId").iscrollview("scrollToElement", this, 0); with error

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on iscrollview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'scrollToElement'
```

I include relevant js and css files and I mentioned in scroll content div as data-iscroll=""

Please suggest me how to enable scroll on input box focus